# How to "print" console logs in Tkinter?

Tags: python, logging, tkinter, console

I read some similar questions, but I don't think they answer mine.

I have a basic code to count to 10 after clicking the button "run" in a GUI:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

def count_to_10():
    for i in range(1,11):
        sleep(0.5)
        print(i)
        counter_label.after(0, counter_label.config(text=i))
    return

def GUI():
    root = Tk()

    run_button = Button(root, text="run", command=count_to_10)
    run_button.pack()

    global counter_label
    counter_label = Label(root, text="counter")
    counter_label.pack()

    root.mainloop()

GUI()
```

I expect the `counter_label` text to change from 1 to 10 after every iteration from the `count_to_10` function. **The label does change when the functions returns, *not* while it runs.**

The console output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The label change:

[The label only changes once to 10 after the end of the function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijxoX.png)

The same result goes to other widgets like `scrolledtext, Text,` and such.

How can I make the label (or any text-related widget) change while the function runs?

Thanks for your help!

PS: It is kind of like having the console output on the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the `x.after()` method. Simply use the `config` or `configure` method. Like this: `counter_label.configure(text=i)` then your should let root update the main window with this line: `root.update()` (root should be global or pass as argument).

**Complete code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep


def count_to_10():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        sleep(0.5)
        print(i)
        counter_label.configure(text=i)  # Update the text in "Label" widget.
        root.update()  # Let root update the main window.


def GUI():
    global root
    root = Tk()

    run_button = Button(root, text="run", command=count_to_10)
    run_button.pack()

    global counter_label
    counter_label = Label(root, text="counter")
    counter_label.pack()

    root.mainloop()


GUI()
```

**GUI:**

[image: GUI]

**Console output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

**Note:**

You Label has changed only once (when the counter was 10) because the `root` was not able to updating and it has been updated when your `count_to_10` function has returned (after `for` loop) and of course the last number was the `10`.

Comment: Thanks so much! This did exactly what I wanted to!

Answer (score 0):

You used `after()` in a wrong way.  Also do not use `time.sleep()` in tkinter application as it will block tkinter mainloop from updating widgets.

Change `count_to_10()` as below:

```
def count_to_10(n=1):
    counter_label.config(text=n)
    if n < 10:
        counter_label.after(500, count_to_10, n+1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Luckily it is possible to update even with the `time.sleep()` function using @milanbalazs method!